# Grid is giving auto margin to print page

Tags: html, css, printing, grid

I am printing barcodes label from web page. but when it goes to print preview page it gives auto margin to the blocks .
I have provided an image which clearly explains what is the my problem. I tried with page break but it did not work though.

```
**html css code**

    <style>
        .main__ {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 4px 1fr;
            grid-template-columns: [linename] 4px;
            grid-template-columns: [linename1] 5px [linename2 linename3];
            grid-template-columns: minmax(4px, 1fr);
            grid-template-columns: fit-content(50%);
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 200px);
            grid-column-gap: 25px;
            grid-row-gap: 50px;
        }

        @media print {

            body *,
                {
                display: none;
                margin: 0px !important;
                padding: 0px !important;
            }

            #main {
                display: block;
            }

            .main__ {
                page-break-after: always !important;
            }
        }
```

```
    <div class="">

        <div>
            <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->

            <section class="content pt-3">
                <div class="">

                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- left column -->
                        <div class="">
                            <!-- Input addon -->
                            <div class="cards">
                                <div class="main__">
                                    @foreach ($barcodes as $barcode)
                                        @for ($i = 0; $i < $barcode->product_quantity; $i++)
                                            <div class="pagebreak">
                                                <div
                                                    style="width: 76mm / 2; height:25mm; margin-left:-5px; text-align:center; ">
                                                    <small style="  font-size:20px; font-weight:bold">VS
                                                        Mart</small>
                                                    <center class="mb-2" style="text-align:left; margin-left:15px;">
                                                        {!! DNS1D::getBarcodeSVG($barcode->barcode, 'CODABAR', 2, 32, 'black', true) !!}</center>
                                                    <span
                                                        style="margin-top:-10px !important; text-align:left !important; margin-left:10px; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold">
                                                        {{ substr($barcode->english_name, 0, 27) }}..</span>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <span
                                                        style="margin-top:2px !important; text-align:left !important; font-size:14.5px; font-weight:bold">
                                                        MRP : {{ $barcode->mrp_price }}</span>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <span
                                                        style="margin-top:-40px !important; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold">
                                                        <strong style="font-weight: 900 !important">Sale Price
                                                            :</strong> <span
                                                            style="font-size: 15px">{{ $barcode->sale_price }}</span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        @endfor
                                    @endforeach
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <!-- Repeat Above Code -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.row -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card -->
                </div>
                <!--/.col (left) -->
        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
```

Sales price is not printing on the same print page. It has gone down.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE39Q.png)

Comment: Warning: This property has been replaced by the break-after property. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after)

Comment: still not working sir

Comment: Use auto instead of always

Comment: Still not working sir.

Comment: Why is it happening ? why automargins are applying ?? Sir

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Hello sir please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Can you give me an online fiddle?

Comment: Okay Sir . https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-3jnybk?file=index.html

Comment: That snippet doesn't work, adjust please.